# implode values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
Num  Name

1    abcd
2    nan
3    nan
4    efdg
5    nan
6    hij
7    nan
8    nan
9   nan
10   nan
11   xyz

# output 

# need output like where we find nulls:
(2,3)  , 5 , (7,10)
```

I've tried grouping data.

Answer (score 1):

Define a groupchange when swapping between *not nan* and *nan*. Then you can derive a group using `cumsum` and group using `min` and `max`

```
df['group']=(df.Name.isna() != df.Name.isna().shift(1)).cumsum()

df_agg = df.groupby('group').agg({'Name':'first','Num':['min','max']})

output = [(a,b) if a!=b else a for a,b in df_agg.loc[df_agg[('Name','first')].isna(),[('Num','min'),('Num','max')]].values]
```

this results in the desired output in a list

```
[(2, 3), 5, (7, 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

This filters the df to only include the `NaN` values, and uses `groupby()` to to group the changes between `NaN` and `non NaN` values. Lastly we use `iloc` to select the first and last value in the `Num` column and use `dict.fromkeys()` to select only the unique values, and preserve the order.

```
(df.loc[df['Name'].isna(),'Num']
.astype('str')
.groupby(df['Name'].isna().diff().ne(0).cumsum())
.agg(lambda x: ','.join(list(dict.fromkeys(x.iloc[[0,-1]])))))
```

Output:

```
Name
2     2,3
4       5
6    7,10
```